# shopify authentication with firebase

Tags: java, firebase, oauth, shopify

I have been working on a project where I have to develop an android web application of a website that's made with Shopify. I used java for the purpose and in my app, I used firebase authentication because the client wants to store data in firebase. Now the problem is when the user logs in through my app, he gets to see the website view but needs to log in again since the website is on Shopify. Is there any way by which Shopify authenticates the user data from firebase data so the user doesn't have to provide details again?

I searched a lot about it and its something to do with OAuth and access tokens, but I have no clue how to integrate it. Someone, please help me with a solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Shopify Plus plan, you can auth user on your app backend using [Multipass](https://shopify.dev/api/multipass)

Documentation starts with the description of the very similar problem to yours:

> You're the owner of a successful website forum. All of your users must log in to the forum to contribute. Members of your forum can then purchase a forum t-shirt through your Shopify store. Unfortunately, your users have to log in to the forum first and then log in to your Shopify store before they can purchase a t-shirt.

> Multipass login is for store owners who have a separate website and a Shopify store. It redirects users from the website to the Shopify store and seamlessly logs them in with the same email address they used to sign up for the original website. If no account with that email address exists yet, one is created. There is no need to synchronize any customer databases.

By the way, storing e-commerce data outside Shopify is not the cheapest thing to do so I would reconsider the requirements.

Comment: The task is to convert a shopify website into a android web application and so I made the app in java but the client wanted an authentication at the start of the app so I used firebase to store data. Is there any alternative which can be used for the purpose which is cheap

Comment: What you are creating is a headless app and they are never cheap. Doing that without Shopify Plus makes no sense as there will be lots of challenges like this in the future. Basically, the budget must be increased or some features must go off the table.

Comment: But can't anything else be done because the plan is very expensive(1,50,000/month). Is there anything we can do related to OAuth2.0 aur access tokens to allow shopify fetch data from firebase and authenticate the user just like we do when signing into a app using google or yahoo account. My thinking is that first user authenticates through firebase and in app, the shopify asks permission to read data from firebase and authenticate the user

Comment: @AayushMittal no, you can try to do a workaround by disabling the captcha and trying to log in the user by opening the browser and sending a form request for him or something like that but you will end up fixing it over and over, plus it could stop working at any point in time. Also, you will have to keep passwords in sync in plain text with Shopify, which means a lot of responsibility, bugs, and bots. OAuth2.0 is used for app auth not customer auth so your focus on it is wrong.

Comment: One more important note to take is you get shopify wrong. In a way, you can't make *Shopify do something for you*. You just can't plug in Shopify into 3rd system and overwrite its logic. Shopify gives you API to read/write data and webhooks to subscribe to events. That means you are taking actions around Shopify, not vice-versa.

Comment: Finally, Headless E-Commerce is not meant for small brands (at least in Shopify, but in general it's not possible to run it without a team of devs). Yes, Shopify Plus is a bit expensive, and buying it just for a multipass makes no sense. But this is their business model and nothing can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I am new to this and so had a lot of doubts. One more question. If we make a custom shopify app, is it possible to deploy it on playstore?

Comment: Yes, you just need to remember to follow google play store policies